# Does anyone know how to make these grunge/teared type borders in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, borders

Example:

[image]

Or this one:

[image]

Notice the "torn" effect on the borders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this

1. Get a grunge brush and do your art it will take less time less efforts
2. You can do this manually but it will take more time more efforts.

so **I suggest you to get grunge brush rather than making it manually,**

for download brush check this :

http://free-brushes.com/2008/09/21/torn_paper_brush_set.html

and if you have time than:

**make a document erase the corner's according to your need and you'll get the same output..**

[image]

I did the same to show you,its kind of heavy/ugly borders, coz i did not reduced the eraser brush size, i realized after completing it :(:(

Hope you got the  idea, That how to do this

Answer (score 4):

There is always the wooden table method:

take a brush, paper, and some black ink and then sketch a rectangle.

Photograph it with your cell phone or high-res camera, convert to B&W.

Use this image as a `layer mask`. Adjust it, rotate it etc as desired.

Using a layer mask has the advantage of being non-destructive.